# How to create a generic method overload in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

I have 3 functions and they are branches of the same type.

```
public interface k
{
    void CreateOrUpdate(IList<TagInfoForRecommender> tagList, IndexType indexType);
    void CreateOrUpdate(IList<ArtifactInfoForRecommender> artifactList, IndexType indexType);
    void CreateOrUpdate(IList<UserInfoForRecommender> userList, IndexType indexType);
}
```

I would like to create one generic type where the implemented class that inherits the interface can write overloads methods of the function.

I have tried

```
public interface k
{    
    void CreateOrUpdate<T>(IList<T> tagList, IndexType indexType) 
        where T : BaseInfoForRecommender;
}
```

But it can only create one method in the implemented class.

I want to create overloads in

```
public class d : K
{
    CreateOrUpdate<TagInfoForRecommender>(IList<TagInfoForRecommender> tagList, IndexType indexType)
    {
        //impelement sth
    }

    CreateOrUpdate<TagInfoForRecommender>(IList<TagInfoForRecommender> tagList, IndexType indexType)
    {
        //impelement sth
    } 
}
```

Comment: It's not clear where the overloads would come in. Could you give a *complete* (but minimal) example of what you'd like to be able to do?

Comment: Please, write some code (the variant you want even if it does not compile).

Comment: I have edited the post. I want the overloads in the implemented interface

Comment: This is not what generics are for. They are supposed to give a template which works the same, regardless of `T`. Otherwise you will have to branch on `typeof(T)` inside the method, and it hardly makes the design better. Is this some kind of a repository pattern? Because EF/NHibernate usually have generic create/update methods which don't care about the exact type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a generic interface

```
public interface K<T> where T : BaseInfoForRecommender{
  void CreateOrUpdate(IList<T> list, IndexType indexType); 
}
```

and then implement the interface multiple times for each type

```
public class d : K<TagInfoForRecommender>,
                 K<ArtifactInfoForRecommender>, 
                 K<UserInfoForRecommender> {
  public void CreateOrUpdate(IList<TagInfoForRecommender> list, IndexType indexType) {...}
  public void CreateOrUpdate(IList<ArtifactInfoForRecommender> list, IndexType indexType) {...}
  public void CreateOrUpdate(IList<UserInfoForRecommender> list, IndexType indexType) {...}
}
```

Comment: My only concern with your answer (that I found pretty nice), it's when you have only the return type that change the signature. You will have to (implement explicitly your methods and) cast your instance on a specific interface, otherwise you can't access to your methods. Even, if it allows to avoid exceptions and type checking like my answer. It can be annoying to always cast your instance to access each method. Correct me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: @romain-aga No you are right. Sometimes it can be cumbersome but it depends on the rest of the application and how it uses the code. But in this case the method signature is always different and you do not need to implement it explicitly.

Comment: You can always add a generic CreateOrUpdate that would call the specific CreateOrUpdate  `public void CreateOrUpdate<T>(IList<T> list, IndexType indexType)
            where T : BaseInfoForRecommender
        {
            ((K<T>)this).CreateOrUpdate(list, indexType);
        }`   You do run the risk of causing a run-time error if you call that method with a type that isn't implemented.

Comment: It can create only one or as much as I want in the implemented class, is that right?

Comment: This is the closest to what I wanted but I think I should not be doing that.

Comment: It would call any that you have implemented and throw a run-time exception on any that you did not implement.  It isn't a best practice because it makes the code less clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.

The only thing that can get close of what you are trying to achieve (if I understand your problem well) is by doing some type checking:

```
public interface IAbstraction
{
    void CreateOrUpdate<T>(IList<T> tagList, IndexType indexType)
        where T : BaseInfoForRecommender;
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class Concrete : IAbstraction
{
    void CreateOrUpdate<T>(IList<T> tagList, IndexType indexType)
        where T : BaseInfoForRecommender
    {
         var dict = new Dictionary<Type, Action<IList<object>, IndexType>()
         {
             { typeof(TagInfoForRecommender),
                 (tagList, indexType) => CreateOrUpdateTagInfoForRecommender(list.Cast<TagInfoForRecommender>(), index) },

             { typeof(ArtifactInfoForRecommender),
                 (tagList, indexType) => CreateOrUpdateArtifactInfoForRecommender(list.Cast<ArtifactInfoForRecommender>(), index) },

             { typeof(UserInfoForRecommender),
                 (tagList, indexType) => CreateOrUpdateUserInfoForRecommender(list.Cast<UserInfoForRecommender>(), index) },
         };
         dict[typeof(T)](tagList.Cast<object>(), indexType);
    }

    private CreateOrUpdateTagInfoForRecommender(IList<TagInfoForRecommender> tagList, IndexType indexType)
    {
    }

    private CreateOrUpdateArtifactInfoForRecommender(IList<ArtifactInfoForRecommender> tagList, IndexType indexType)
    {
    }

    private CreateOrUpdateUserInfoForRecommender(IList<UserInfoForRecommender> tagList, IndexType indexType)
    {
    }
}
```

I guess you can write something better, since I didn't try my code (you should have some errors). But you have the main idea.